# Resign keyboard when viewController is dismissed

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, swift

i have a cell which include a textField. When the viewController is opened i've assigned this to be the first responder by following code:

```
cell.namTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

When i dismiss the viewController the keyboard hides with a delay, which does not look good. How can i resignTheFirstResponder when the viewController? when the textField is in the cell and i cant access it in a function?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `self.view.endEditing(true)`, which will traverse all the subviews in a view (here the controller's main view) and force (this is the `true` part) any view that is currently the first responder to resign.

I guess it would make sense to use it inside `viewWillDisappear:` in order to hide the keyboard before the controller is dismissed (or another one is pushed etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following line of code to dismiss keyboard.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

This method will dismiss any keyboard present in any of your application views

Answer (score 1):

try this method to hide keyboard :-

```
- (void) hideKeyboard:(BOOL)hidden
{
    NSArray *arrWindows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    if ([arrWindows count] > 1)
    {
        UIWindow *keyboardWindow = [arrWindows objectAtIndex:1];
        [keyboardWindow setHidden:hidden];
    }
}
```